# Activity not starting for no reason

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

```
public class NinthScreen extends Activity{

    Button result;
    EditText number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ninth_screen);

        result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReveal);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMagicNumber);

        result.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.MindReader.TenthScreen");
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("n", number.getText().toString());
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(number.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I can't see what's wrong in my code and why it doesn't start for the next class of activity and why the app crashes, please help !?

Comment: what error you get, can you be more clear please

Comment: Yeah, the stack trace would help..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.MindReader.TenthScreen");
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TenthScreen.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to go to 'AndroidManifest.xml' 
and add the following line, after your MainActivity activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.controller.NinthScreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

- NOTE: instead of com.example.controller, include your own package location (scroll to the top of your activity code's document) 
 - NOTE: use whichever android.intent. action and category that fits your Activity, look this up [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

the complete xml should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.controller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.controller.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.controller.NinthScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

try this, and post again if it doesn't work.

Comment: seems like Badgerati got it,
Next time it would be great if you let us know what steps you have or haven't taken to cause the requested result.